# Проблемы с компиляцией GWT проекта

Tags: java, веб-программирование, gwt

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь скомпилировать проект GWT. 
Использую следующие библиотеки

```
commons-configuration-1.6.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
aopalliance.jar
gin-1.0.jar
guice-2.0.jar
mvp4g-1.2.0.jar
```

Руководствуюсь тутором отсюда: https://cambiatablog.wordpress.com/2010/12/04/gwt-and-mvp4g-tutorial-1/

При запуске проекта получаю огромный лог ошибок.
В чем может быть проблема?

```
 SPAM: Resolving com.google.gwt.animation.client.Animation
  SPAM: Found type 'com.google.gwt.animation.client.Animation'
    SPAM: Found type 'java.lang.Object'
      SPAM: Resolving method getClass
        SPAM: Found type 'java.lang.Class'
          SPAM: Resolving method createForClass
            SPAM: Found type 'java.lang.String'
              SPAM: Resolving field CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
                SPAM: Found type 'java.util.Comparator'
                  WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
SPAM: Resolving com.google.gwt.cell.client.DateCell
  SPAM: Found type 'com.google.gwt.cell.client.DateCell'
    SPAM: Resolving method <init>
      SPAM: Found type 'com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat'
        SPAM: Resolving field patternParts
          SPAM: Found type 'java.util.ArrayList'
            SPAM: Resolving method forEach
            SPAM: Resolving method removeIf
            SPAM: Resolving method replaceAll
              SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.Consumer'
              SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.Predicate'
              SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.UnaryOperator'
                WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
                WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
                WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
                SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.Function'
                  WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
SPAM: Resolving java.lang.Runnable
  SPAM: Found type 'java.lang.Runnable'
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
SPAM: Resolving java.util.Arrays
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.Arrays'
    SPAM: Resolving method parallelPrefix
    SPAM: Resolving method setAll
      SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.BinaryOperator'
      SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.IntFunction'
        WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
        SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.BiFunction'
        WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
          WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
    SPAM: Resolving method stream
      SPAM: Found type 'java.util.stream.Stream'
        SPAM: Resolving method collect
          SPAM: Found type 'java.util.stream.Collector'
            SPAM: Resolving method supplier
            SPAM: Resolving method accumulator
              SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.Supplier'
              SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.BiConsumer'
                WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
                WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
        SPAM: Resolving method flatMapToDouble
          SPAM: Found type 'java.util.stream.DoubleStream'
            SPAM: Resolving method collect
            SPAM: Resolving method flatMap
              SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.ObjDoubleConsumer'
              SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.DoubleFunction'
        SPAM: Resolving method flatMapToInt
                WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
                WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
          SPAM: Found type 'java.util.stream.IntStream'
        SPAM: Resolving method flatMapToLong
            SPAM: Resolving method collect
          SPAM: Found type 'java.util.stream.LongStream'
              SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer'
            SPAM: Resolving method collect
            SPAM: Resolving method flatMap
                WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
              SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.ObjLongConsumer'
              SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.LongFunction'
                WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
                WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
        SPAM: Resolving method mapToDouble
        SPAM: Resolving method mapToInt
        SPAM: Resolving method mapToLong
          SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction'
          SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.ToIntFunction'
          SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.ToLongFunction'
            WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
            WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
            WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
SPAM: Resolving java.util.DoubleSummaryStatistics
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.DoubleSummaryStatistics'
    SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.DoubleConsumer'
      WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
SPAM: Resolving java.util.IntSummaryStatistics
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.IntSummaryStatistics'
    SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.IntConsumer'
      WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
SPAM: Resolving java.util.LongSummaryStatistics
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.LongSummaryStatistics'
    SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.LongConsumer'
      WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.BiPredicate
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.BooleanSupplier
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.DoubleBinaryOperator
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.DoublePredicate
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.DoubleSupplier
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.DoubleToIntFunction
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.BiPredicate'
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.BooleanSupplier'
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.DoubleBinaryOperator'
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.DoublePredicate'
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.DoubleToLongFunction
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.DoubleUnaryOperator
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.DoubleSupplier'
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.DoubleToIntFunction'
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.DoubleToLongFunction'
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.DoubleUnaryOperator'
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.IntPredicate
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.IntSupplier
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.IntToDoubleFunction
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator'
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.IntToLongFunction
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.IntPredicate'
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.IntSupplier'
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.IntToDoubleFunction'
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.IntToLongFunction'
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.LongBinaryOperator
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.LongPredicate
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.LongSupplier
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.LongToDoubleFunction
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.LongToIntFunction
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator'
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.LongBinaryOperator'
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.LongPredicate'
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.LongSupplier'
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.LongToDoubleFunction'
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.LongToIntFunction'
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.LongUnaryOperator
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.LongUnaryOperator'
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.ToDoubleBiFunction
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.ToDoubleBiFunction'
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.ToIntBiFunction
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.ToIntBiFunction'
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
SPAM: Resolving java.util.function.ToLongBiFunction
  SPAM: Found type 'java.util.function.ToLongBiFunction'
    WARN: Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
ERROR: Unable to initialize static dispatcher
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Method com_google_gwt_typedarrays_shared_Uint8ClampedArray_subarray in class com/google/gwt/typedarrays/shared/Uint8ClampedArray has illegal modifiers: 0x1041
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.findClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1150)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.loadClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1223)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.findClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1150)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.loadClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1223)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.findClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1150)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.loadClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1223)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JsValueGlue.set(JsValueGlue.java:220)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:114)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:573)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:315)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:359)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:530)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:368)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR: Failed to load module 'ru.evm.web.gwt.Test' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0' at 127.0.0.1:53791
```